# Identify variable from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, variables

I am passing 2 variables using htaccess. Subject & Brands

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?subject=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?brand=$1 [NC,L]
```

in my function file i am using page detection to include respective modules.

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['subject']))
{
    include_once("templates/pages.php");

}

else if (!empty($_REQUEST['brand']))
{
    include_once("templates/brands_content.php");

}
```

PROBLEM:
I am unable to detect the variable .... its always loading "templates/pages.php"
Can anyone guide me to solve this issue please.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second rule, `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?brand=$1 [NC,L]` will never match because whatever URL you request matches the first one (for subject). There's apparently no difference in the way the URL appears for a subject or brand.

```
http://yourdomain.com/12345
```

Is "12345" a brand or a subject? You either need to make the regular expressions to match subject and brand mutually exclusive (or if not, subject, the first rule, will always match first), or you can explicitly say what is a brand or subject by adding that to your URI:

```
http://yourdomain.com/subject/12345
http://yourdomain.com/brand/12345
```

And your rules would thus be:

```
RewriteRule ^subject/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?subject=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ ?brand=$1 [NC,L]
```